# Tratamento de dados recebidos pela Porta Serial C#

Tags: c#, porta-serial

Quando faço a leitura dos dados da porta Serial em **C#** e adiciono em uma String `RxString` eu recebo as seguintes sequências de caracteres:

> "??\u0002???\u0002???\u0002???\u0002???\u0002???\u0002???\u0002???\u0002?..."

ou

> "???? ??? ??? ??? ???..".

A sequência correta seria números inteiros separados por espaço:

> Exemplo: "123 456 789 1023 0 12 02..."

Código onde recepciono os dados da porta Serial:

```
string RxString;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SerialCOM.PortName = "COM6"; //comboBoxCOM.Text;
    SerialCOM.BaudRate = 9600; // Int32.Parse(comboBoxBR.Text);
    SerialCOM.Parity = Parity.None;
    SerialCOM.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    SerialCOM.DataBits = 8;
    SerialCOM.Open();        
    SerialCOM.DiscardOutBuffer();
    SerialCOM.DiscardInBuffer();
    timerDRAW.Enabled = true; //interval = 1ms
}

private void timerDRAW_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SerialCOM.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialCOM_DataReceived);
}

private void SerialCOM_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sData = (SerialPort)sender;
    {
        if(sData.BytesToRead >= 1) RxString += sData.ReadExisting();
        /...
    }
}
```

Quando transmito os dados de um **Arduíno** para porta Serial tem alguma forma específica de recepcionar os dados?